# Unity Bootstrapper from NuGet is throwing error on App_Start

Tags: c#, unity-container, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

the Microsoft Unity Bootstrapper for Unity 3.0 is throwing an error on this line:

```
FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider(container));
```

with the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.ArrayTypeMismatchException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Attempted to access an element as a type
>   incompatible with the array.

The entirety of the code is here and this was all pre-made and written by the bootstrapper downloaded from nuget.

**Bootstrapper generated file App_Start/UnityMVCActivator.cs**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc;

[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(WebApplication.WebUI.App_Start.UnityWebActivator), "Start")]

namespace WebApplication.WebUI.App_Start
{
    /// <summary>Provides the bootstrapping for integrating Unity with ASP.NET MVC.</summary>
    public static class UnityWebActivator
    {
        /// <summary>Integrates Unity when the application starts.</summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();

            FilterProviders.Providers.Remove(FilterProviders.Providers.OfType<FilterAttributeFilterProvider>().First());
            FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider(container));

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

            // TODO: Uncomment if you want to use PerRequestLifetimeManager
            // Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));
        }
    }
}
```

**Bootstrapper generated file App_Start/UnityConfig.cs**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration;
using WebApplication.Domain.Abstract;
using WebApplication.Domain.Concrete;

namespace WebApplication.WebUI.App_Start
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies the Unity configuration for the main container.
    /// </summary>
    public class UnityConfig
    {
        #region Unity Container
        private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            RegisterTypes(container);
            return container;
        });

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the configured Unity container.
        /// </summary>
        public static IUnityContainer GetConfiguredContainer()
        {
            return container.Value;
        }
        #endregion

        /// <summary>Registers the type mappings with the Unity container.</summary>
        /// <param name="container">The unity container to configure.</param>
        /// <remarks>There is no need to register concrete types such as controllers or API controllers (unless you want to 
        /// change the defaults), as Unity allows resolving a concrete type even if it was not previously registered.</remarks>
        public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            // NOTE: To load from web.config uncomment the line below. Make sure to add a Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration to the using statements.
            //container.LoadConfiguration();

            // TODO: Register your types here
            //container.RegisterType<IProductRepository, EFProductRepository>();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

```
#region Assembly Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc.dll, v3.0.0.0
// C:\Users\James\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Application\packages\Unity.Mvc.3.0.1304.0\lib\Net45\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc.dll
#endregion

using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc
{
    // Summary:
    //     Defines a filter provider for filter attributes that support injection of
    //     Unity dependencies.
    public class UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider : FilterAttributeFilterProvider
    {
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of the Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc.UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider
        //     class.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   container:
        //     The Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer that will be used to inject
        //     the filters.
        public UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider(IUnityContainer container);

        // Summary:
        //     Gets a collection of custom action attributes, and injects them using a Unity
        //     container.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   controllerContext:
        //     The controller context.
        //
        //   actionDescriptor:
        //     The action descriptor.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A collection of custom action attributes.
        protected override IEnumerable<FilterAttribute> GetActionAttributes(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets a collection of controller attributes, and injects them using a Unity
        //     container.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   controllerContext:
        //     The controller context.
        //
        //   actionDescriptor:
        //     The action descriptor.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A collection of controller attributes.
        protected override IEnumerable<FilterAttribute> GetControllerAttributes(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor);
    }
}
```

Packages installed by Unity bootstrapper

```
  <package id="Unity" version="3.0.1304.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Unity.Mvc" version="3.0.1304.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebActivatorEx" version="2.0.4" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Stack:

```
[ArrayTypeMismatchException: Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array.]
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Insert(Int32 index, T item) +58
   System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, T item) +55
   System.Web.Mvc.FilterProviderCollection.InsertItem(Int32 index, IFilterProvider item) +47
   System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(T item) +98
   WebApplication.WebUI.App_Start.UnityWebActivator.Start() in c:\Users\James\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Application\WebApplication.WebUI\App_Start\UnityMvcActivator.cs:18

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +192
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +155
   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +19
   WebActivatorEx.BaseActivationMethodAttribute.InvokeMethod() +236
   WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.RunActivationMethods(Boolean designerMode) +535
   WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.RunPreStartMethods(Boolean designerMode) +48
   WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.Run() +163

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +556
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +132
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +102
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +516

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9882460
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

Comment: Where did you get the UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider ? Nuget or you created. The same code works for me

Comment: I just let unity bootstrapper do it... I'll uninstall and reinstall in that case.

Comment: that didn't help but i'm adding the code for the filter provider written by Microsoft.

Comment: I just posted my working code, in case if you can't troubleshoot.

Comment: your UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider is different to mine. I use Unity.MVC4, I think you have Unity.MVC3

Comment: Even with the Microsoft provided filter provider the code works for me.

Comment: it was very tricky :) Updates my answer with the solution I found.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**UPDATED WITH THE SOLUTION**

Okay, this was very tricky. I have no idea how you manage to get this type of project. You might have upgraded your project type from an earlier version of ASP.NET MVC. Any way below is the answer.

In you Web.Config's runtime Assembly binding section, please add the below.

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: did you use the bootstrapper (by Microsoft) too?... So first you installed Unity 3 (by Microsoft). then you installed the nugget package called Unity MVC4 (by the Brad Vincent guy) then you installed the bootstrapper?

Comment: Regardless of what it should work. This is all I have now. It works fine.  <package id="Unity" version="3.0.1304.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Unity.Mvc" version="3.0.1304.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebActivatorEx" version="2.0" targetFramework="net45" />

Comment: https://github.com/jimmyt1988/WebApplication/tree/master/Application/WebApplication.WebUI - I'll take a look again at everything you've posted.

Comment: Only thing I can see different is that WebActivatorEx... hmm

Comment: Thanks I think this is ASP.NET MVC 5 related. The code I posed was MVC4. Let me try and repro in MVC 5. Your solution is MVC5

Comment: I didn't even know that. i'll re-change the tags. my apologies mate. thanks for taking the time!

Comment: Did you manage to reproduce the error in MVC 5? If so, I'll try out ninject

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42699/discussion-between-spock-and-james-t)

Comment: YEHAAAA, MATE That's bloody working. Christ, how'd you suss that one out!!!? I would NEVER EVER have sussed that out! thankyou so so much. #virtualbeer - Weird thing is this is straight out of the box brand new project.. Visual Studio 2013 Express.. I'll keep this in mind in the future though.

Comment: Now 5.2.3.0 instead of 5.0.0.0 -- had that issue when cloning into git from TFS

Comment: I second what Jimmy said!